# How to looping data in select tag with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, while-loop, laravel-5

Hi i'm beginner using Laravel 5 Framework
i want to ask. how to looping data in select tags with Laravel 5 Framework.

If i using PHP Native like this:

```
<select name="handphone">
<?php 
include "connection.php";
$data_get = mysqli_query($con,"select * from handphone");
while ($get=mysqli_fetch_object($data_get)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $get->idphone ?>"><?php echo $get->namephone ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

How To looping data in select tags using Laravel 5 ?

Comment: are u shure that `mysqli_query` is something about Laravel? show us what u have tried. In Laravel

Comment: I'm usually using PHP Native and using code mysqli_query. I want to ask how to looping select tags in Laravel 5

Comment: Even using just PHP you should use the alternate syntax for the while loop to make it more readable like this `<?=while(condition):?><option value="<?= $get->idphone ?>"><?= $get->namephone ?><?= endwhile; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel you will use something like this

```
$handphones = DB::table('handphone')->all();
```

This will get all the records from the handphone table. 
In your view use the foreach to loop through the results like this.

```
<select>
@foreach($handphones as $handphone)
    <option value="{{$handphone->idphone}}">{{$handphone->namephone}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: $handphones = DB::table('handphone')->all();  << i create this file in folder "app > http > controller" 

Then i create this select tags in folder  "resource > views"

right ?

Comment: Yes exactly. and you will need to pass that $headphones down to the view when you load it from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cleaner way to do it without a loop:

```
{!! Form::label('handphones', 'Handphones') !!}
{!! Form::select('handphones', $handphones , null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

The values have to be stored as the key and the the displayed names as the value.
If you want to select an option by default you pass it as the third parameter.

You need to include "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev" because the html class is not embedded any more.